# CSS arrow (using :after) looks different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm making a downward arrow using CSS. Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/15zxupy9/ and the CSS:

```
.btndown{
    height:40px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#007bff;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
.btndown:after{
    position:relative;
    bottom:-60px;
    left:-15px;
    content:" ";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 30px  0px  30px;
    border-color: #007bff   transparent transparent    transparent;
}
```

This arrow looks fine in Firefox but in Chrome the arrowhead only appear halfway. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Check It Out The fiddle Postion after .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.btndown{
    height:40px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#007bff;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    clear: both;

}
.btndown:after{
    position:absolute;
   bottom:-30px;
    left: -15px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    content:" ";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 30px  0px  30px;
    border-color: #007bff   transparent transparent    transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="btndown">

</div>
```

```
Check It Out The fiddle Postion .btndown:after.....
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kumarrishikesh12/15zxupy9/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
.btndown{
    height:40px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#007bff;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
.btndown:after{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30px;
    left: -15px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    content:" ";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 30px  0px  30px;
    border-color: #007bff   transparent transparent    transparent;
}
```